# In Android, is it possible to keep data connection alive during a voice call?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, android-wake-lock

I am aware that only select network technologies like 3G and 4G allow simultaneous Data and Voice calls. However, is it fully supported and possible in Android? I am working on an app, which should keep on communicating with a server, even when a voice call is on. Is it possible? Do I need some special wake lock, etc to keep a data connection alive in this case?

Comment: I believe android does it automatically if simultaneous data connection is possible

Comment: While you are are on a call there is no need for locks ! it is when the phone is idle that you need locks